# Problems installing PTVS (Python Tools for Visual Studio)

Tags: python, ide, visual-studio-2013

After a couple of weeks working with IDLE, I am trying to add the PTVS extension to VS Express 2013 for Desktop. Following [this page](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PTVS%20Installation), I downloaded the `.msi` installer and run the file. The dialog opens asking for terms agreement and when approving and clicking `Install`, I get an error message:

[image]

So, I went to `www.microsoft.com/visualstudio` but could not find anything specific to the Python addon.

Where should I look for adding Python dev support to my MSVS Express 2013 installation?

Please note that I am using Python for very basic process automation scripting, so no need for web/GUI development, if this matters.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [project site](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PTVS%20Installation), the tools are meant to be use with a paid version of VS, but there seems to be a workaround :

> Install the VS "Community Edition" (recommended)
>   Install the “Express 2013 for Web” or
>   “Express 2013 for Desktop” package with Update 3 or later
>   Install PTVS